# afterCompose never executes on initialization

Tags: zk

I have a controller that extends window and implments IdSpace, AfterCompose.
But the function afterCompose never executes when the controller is initialized. A cant figure out what I am missing. My code for this part:

**DataTemplateWindowController.java**

```
public class DataTemplateWindowController extends Window implements IdSpace, AfterCompose {
   ...
   public DataTemplateWindowController() {
      Executions.createComponents("dataTemplate.zul", this, null);
      Selectors.wireComponents(this, this, false);
      Selectors.wireEventListeners(this, this);
   }

   @Override
   public void afterCompose() {
      Do something smart!!
   }
}
```

And the initializetion.
**HomeWindowController.java**

```
public class HomeWindowController extends SelectorComposer<Component> {
    ...

    @Wire
    Window homeWindow;

    DataTemplateWindowController fa2;

    public void setDataTemplate() {
        fa2 = new FA2WindowController();
        fa2.setParent(homeWindow);
    }
}
```

The page loads fine, but the afterCompose function never executes.

I know that i can just avoid implementing AfterCompose and then run the function fa2.afterCompose() after initialization but I expect AfterCompose to be able to do the job for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the javadoc of AfterCompose (of org.zkoss.zk.ui.ext.AfterCompose) interface :

> Implemented by a component if it wants to know when ZK loader created
>   it. If this interface is implemented, {@link #afterCompose} is called,
>   after ZK loader creates this component, all of its children, and
>   assigns all properties defined in the ZUML page. It is so-called
>   "compose".

So the method : "afterCompose" will never be call automatically by your own java code (the code in your method setDataTemplate() in your example). It will only be called if you use your component in a ZUL page.

And you can also see in the Javadoc of org.zkoss.zk.ui.ext.AfterCompose:

> If it is created manually, it is caller's job to invoke {@link#afterCompose}.

If you don't need to set any properties or child in you afterCompose process, just don't use this interface and put your code in the constructor, otherwise, you will have to call it manually when you need it (usually in the doAfterCompose of your SelectorComposer) :

```
public class HomeWindowController extends SelectorComposer<Component> {
    ...

    @Wire
    Window homeWindow;

    DataTemplateWindowController fa2;

    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        setDataTemplate();
    }

    public void setDataTemplate() {
        fa2 = new FA2WindowController();
        fa2.setParent(homeWindow);
        fa2.afterCompose();
    }
}
```

Comment: window already implements idspace so that's also not needed to be repeated.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, i totally missed this fact. I still have some overall ZK to learn ;-).